# Android: ListView header and footer Behavior is not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[image: Here is my Image not yet scrolled]

> This is the view when i'm scrolling it.. it added extra layout that expand some space within my listview item

[image]

> What listview properties should i assign to fix it?
>
> Here is my List View

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:saveEnabled="false" />
</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Number: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNumberValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="222-222-222-222"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> My Initialization of ListView

```
    private void setupListViewAdapter(ListView listView, View headerView, View footerView){
    listView.setDividerHeight(5);
    listView.setFadingEdgeLength(200);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);
    listView.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);
    listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
    listView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I think you have to post full xml file.

Comment: it was almost 700 lines.. and it said it's more than the allowed characters. it stated allowed body is 30000chars and mine is 31000+ chars..

Comment: go through that properly, do you use android:layout_weight ?

Comment: here is the link of my layout http://pastebin.com/UrwRtnaB

Comment: yes im using it there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code made my listview display unwanted view.

```
  private void initListView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    View headerViewROR = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vp_ror_header, null,false);
    View footerViewROR = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vp_remarks_footer, null,false);

    listView.addHeaderView(headerViewROR, null, false); //--> multiple occurrence need to be removed
    listView.addFooterView(footerViewROR, null, false); //--> multiple occurrence need to be removed
    setupListViewAdapter(listView, headerViewROR,footerViewROR);
}
```

> Initialize adding header and footer twice that causes the listview behavior.. because i also called the *listView.addFooterView* to my *setupListViewAdapter* function.

```
    private void setupListViewAdapter(ListView listView, View headerView, View footerView){
    listView.setDividerHeight(5);
    listView.setFadingEdgeLength(200);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);//--> here is another assignment
    listView.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);//--> here is another assignment
    listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    listView.requestFocus(0);
    listView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing yu can have more than one header and footer in list view .Every time you call addHeader() it will add the view in list header . In one case when your list items are empty . Then you need to setAdapter(null) .Then only you will be able to see views you added in header and footer ..